# Duplicate CSS code from webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less

I am making a component library and I am running into a webpack issue I can not seem to get solved. The problem is that I want the ability to use components individually.

So let's say Project A uses the Button component and Project B uses DropdownButton. Ideally I want to import only code related to Button in Project A so that DropdownButton wouldn't be in the codebase.

Currently I am generating a transpiled file with webpack for each component in a lib folder. So after the build is done i am left with

`lib
   - Button.js
   - Button.css
   - DropdownButton.js
   - DropdownButton.css`

So I can import it like this in Project A.

`import Button from 'comps/lib/Button';`

`import 'comps/lib/Button.css';`

All is well until Project C needs both Button and DropdownButton. Then when I import both I get the Button.css and Button.js code twice.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using webpack 2.6.1

Answer (score 1):

In each component you can define its dependencies as *[externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)* when building for production - and that will guarantee that they won't be bundled.

```
// webpack.config.js

{
  ...
  externals: isDev ? null : Object.keys(require('./package.json').dependencies))
}
```

Of course - when developing you can bundle everything for convenience, but when building the actual component for consumption - mark its dependencies as externals.

In your example - DropdownButton will have Button as a `require('Button')`, and the project that consumes both will bundle it only once.